# Access form with combo box not running query

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

This database is to store data for a chemistry lab.  This is happening on several data entry forms.

The main form has textboxes and combo boxes that collect data that is stored into table 1. This data applies to each sample (which will get one record on the main data table).  Then the subform on the bottom of the main form collects data for sample ID and the generated values.

This data is stored in table 2. There are 2 buttons on the form. One appends the new data to the main data table (#3) and deletes the records from tables 1 and 2. The second button simply deletes the newly generated records.

The combo box on the main form that is used to identify the instrument number "cmbInstrument" has simple code used to run the update query that will update the details of the instrument that the general end user does not need to know, but an auditor will request.

```
Private Sub cmbInstrument_AfterUpdate()
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryUpdateInstrument" 
End Sub
```

The query works if you select an instrument from the combo box, click into the subform, then click back into the main form. (there is a calibration date box that will auto-populate once the query runs).
What could be keeping the query from running until the form-subform-form selection occurs? Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Is Instrument tied to a data field? The code won't run until you lose focus or tab off the control

Comment: I wanted to end user to select an intrument ID from a combo list. Then, when they moved to the next textbox, the calibration date would autopopulate for them. This would let them know if the instrument was able to be used that day. This query will not run until the subform is selected and then the main form is selected again.  So, if the end user does not do this sequence of setting focus between the forms, the query doesn't run and the additional calibration data for the select instrument is not included in the new records.

Comment: I had to read all that and I can't see that you answered my question. It looks like you just repeated your problem 6 weeks later